# raw vs. html_safe vs. h to unescape html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

Suppose I have the following string

```
@x = "<a href='#'>Turn me into a link</a>"
```

In my view, I want a link to be displayed. That is, I don't want everything in @x to be unescaped and displayed as a string. What's the difference between using

```
<%= raw @x %>
<%= h @x %>
<%= @x.html_safe %>
```

?

Comment: Since nobody mentioned it I figured I'd also mention there's `<%== @x %>` which is an alias to `<%= raw(@x) %>` https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#output-safety

Answer (score 404, accepted):

Considering Rails 3:

`html_safe` actually "sets the string" as HTML Safe (it's a little more complicated than that, but it's basically it). This way, you can return HTML Safe strings from helpers or models at will.

`h` can only be used from within a controller or view, since it's from a helper. It will force the output to be escaped. It's not really deprecated, but you most likely won't use it anymore: the only usage is to "revert" an `html_safe` declaration, pretty unusual.

Prepending your expression with `raw` is actually equivalent to calling `to_s` chained with `html_safe` on it, but is declared on a helper, just like `h`, so it can only be used on controllers and views.

"[SafeBuffers and Rails 3.0](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/02/01/safebuffers-and-rails-3-0/)" is a nice explanation on how the `SafeBuffer`s (the class that does the `html_safe` magic) work.

Comment: I wouldn't say that `h` will ever be deprecated. Using `"Hi<br/>#{h@ user.name}".html_safe` is quite common and an accepted use.

Comment: @Maletor interesting usage, though I still think it falls into the "unusual" category.

Comment: String#html_safe actually returns an instance of ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer which wraps the original string and is #html_safe? .  The original string does not become #html_safe? after calling #html_safe on it.

Comment: Note that there is a subtle difference between `raw` and `html_safe` in practice: `raw(nil)` returns an empty string, while `nil.html_safe` throws an exception.

Comment: so why the heck is html_safe stripping out hyphens from my urls?

Comment: `h` will not "revert" an html_safe declaration.  When an string is `html_safe`, `h` will do nothing.

Answer (score 130):

I think it bears repeating: `html_safe` does **not** HTML-escape your string. In fact, it will prevent your string from being escaped.

```
<%= "<script>alert('Hello!')</script>" %>
```

will put:

```
&lt;script&gt;alert(&#x27;Hello!&#x27;)&lt;/script&gt;
```

into your HTML source (yay, so safe!), while:

```
<%= "<script>alert('Hello!')</script>".html_safe %>
```

will pop up the alert dialog (are you sure that's what you want?). So you probably don't want to call `html_safe` on any user-entered strings.

Comment: In other words, html_safe is not "please make this html safe", it's the opposite - it is you the programmer telling rails that "this string is html safe, promise!"

Comment: actually I came here to figure out if it actually does _unescape_ or if it just makes a mark that it is not necessary _to_escape_. Quite a difference. Oh well, off to read the source code then.

Comment: The concept of "html_safe" is just a meta flag on the string.  Marking something as `html_safe` does *not* escape *nor* unescape.  While the end result of marking something as *not* HTML safe, and then using the implicit escaping of the ERB <%= tag, might be the same as unescaping data and then re-escaping it on output, functionally it's doing neither.  Kind of like the difference of (6 * -1 * -1), vs. 6.

Answer (score 53):

The difference is between Rails’ `html_safe()` and `raw()`. There is an excellent post by Yehuda Katz on this, and it really boils down to this:

```
def raw(stringish)

  stringish.to_s.html_safe

end
```

Yes, `raw()` is a wrapper around `html_safe()` that forces the input to String and then calls `html_safe()` on it. It’s also the case that `raw()` is a helper in a module whereas `html_safe()` is a method on the String class which makes a new ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer instance — that has a `@dirty` flag in it.

Refer to "[Rails’ html_safe vs. raw](https://yehudakatz.com/2010/02/01/safebuffers-and-rails-3-0/)".

Answer (score 40):

1. **`html_safe`** :

   Marks a string as trusted safe. It will be inserted into HTML with no additional escaping performed.

   ```
   "<a>Hello</a>".html_safe
   #=> "<a>Hello</a>"

   nil.html_safe
   #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `html_safe' for nil:NilClass
   ```
2. **`raw`** :

   `raw` is just a wrapper around `html_safe`. Use `raw` if there are chances that the string will be `nil`.

   ```
   raw("<a>Hello</a>")
   #=> "<a>Hello</a>"

   raw(nil)
   #=> ""
   ```
3. **`h`** alias for **`html_escape`** :

   A utility method for escaping HTML tag characters. Use this method to escape any unsafe content.

   In Rails 3 and above it is used by default so you don't need to use this method explicitly

Answer (score 28):

The best safe way is: `<%= sanitize @x %>`

It will avoid XSS!

Answer (score 3):

In Simple Rails terms:

`h` remove html tags into number characters so that rendering won't break your html

`html_safe` sets a boolean in string so that the string is considered as html save

`raw` It converts to html_safe to string

Comment: The answer is correct: h is html_escape ... [from the Rails code base](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6-0-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/output_safety.rb#L20-L25)

Answer (score 0):

#### Short and Simple

Let's assume we can't trust user input.

#### Bad:

`user_input.html_safe  # asking for trouble`

#### Good:

`user_input.html_escape  # or`

`h(user_input)  # in some view`

#### Inputs we control:

`trusted_input_only.html_safe`

that should be fine. but be careful what your trusted inputs are. They must only be generated from your app.