# Undo html escape with ruby on rails data migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration, html-escape

I have a database, and currently many of the items within it have been html escaped.  I need to undo this (don't ask why!), for which I'll carry out a data migration.

But is the a way to un-escape these strings?  I've not been able to find anything..

Comment: Does the answer to this question help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251284/raw-vs-html-safe-vs-h-to-unescape-html

Answer (score 4):

Ruby's [CGI::unescapeHTML](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/cgi/1.9.2/CGI#unescapeHTML-class_method) can do HTML unescaping.

```
Unescape a string that has been HTML-escaped

  CGI::unescapeHTML("Usage: foo &quot;bar&quot; &lt;baz&gt;")
     # => "Usage: foo \"bar\" <baz>"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the [htmlentities](http://htmlentities.rubyforge.org/) gem

Answer (score 0):

If i understand it correct you need to replace strings like `&gt;` to `>`. If so - check xml documentation and replace required strings with their real values. I dont code in ruby, so this one you got to figure out :]
[XML special characters](http://xml.silmaril.ie/specials.html)

Comment: so you mean explicitly search for things that (say) apostrophe's could have been turned into and change them back?  I was wondering whether there was a less arduous way..