# interpreting escaped html

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, xml

I am using rails 3.0 and I have an xml file where I store the content of my webpage. So for example, to fill in the body section of a given html page, I extract the content of the  tag using REXML methods in ruby.

I would like to store a content with HTML tag inside this XML tag. Say, the following is my favorite content:

`<body><strong>XXX</strong></body>`

I am inserting this text in its escaped version so that XML parser doesn't interpret it as some content.

`"&lt;strong&gt; XXX &lt;/strong&gt;"`

Running seeds.rb file, I am reading this content to the database and eventually render it as an html page.

I tried many methods, I was unable to obtain what I want, namely: **XXX**

thanks for your help.

Comment: this site
http://yehudakatz.com/2010/02/01/safebuffers-and-rails-3-0/
and this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251284/raw-vs-html-safe-vs-h-to-unescape-html

were helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Another easy to output raw content

`<%== @content.body %>`

It's exactly the same as

`<%= raw @content.body %>`

it's just a shorthand method to output raw content

Answer (score 0):

try putting the html inside a [`CDATA`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) section (unescaped):

```
<xmlNode>
    <![CDATA[
    <body><strong>XXX</strong></body>
    ]]>
</xmlNode>
```

Comment: I already tried what you have suggested here. And no success. Actually, It doesn't work as long as the string is .html_safe declared in the controller. thx

Answer (score 0):

solved the problem, in my XML file, I have this content entered unescaped as it is:

`<body>
<strong>XXX</strong>
</body>`

in my seeds.rb file, I read the child of  node with:

`k.children[1].to_s`

and finally in the controller, I declare the content as `.html_safe`:

`<%= content_tag(:div, @content.body.html_safe) %>`