# Rails: difference between <%= and <%==?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I'm looking at legacy code that has all erb interpolations with `<%==` ... And I've never used that before.

What is it for? What does it do differently from `<%=` ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's shorthand to output raw content.

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5533614/2128691

> `<%== @content.body %>`
>
> Is exactly the same as
>
> `<%= raw @content.body %>`

Comment: +1.  learned something new!

Comment: Is there documentation for this shorthand?

Comment: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#output-safety (linked from OP Question comment)