# How do I render RedCloth html in a view in Rails3?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, redcloth

In rails 2, I use <%=h %> to display HTML-generated by RedCloth, but how do I do that in Rails 3?

```
<%= raw RedCloth.new(@review).to_html %>
```

Comment: This should work fine in Rails 3. What's your output - escaped HTML instead of raw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<%= raw %>`.

Reference: [raw vs. html_safe vs. h to unescape html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251284/raw-vs-html-safe-vs-h-to-unescape-html)

Comment: hi, it still doesn't work...I updated mine to show what I am doing...?