# Marking a string as HTML safe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, navigation, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I am trying to build my first Rails application and I'm using [Ryan Heath's navigation_helper](https://github.com/rpheath/navigation_helper) plugin to give me the current class in my navigation.  I built my named routes as follows:

```
match 'games' => 'games#index', :as => :games
match 'new' => 'games#new', :as => :new
match 'previous' => 'games#previous', :as => :previous
match 'settings' => 'settings#index', :as => :settings
```

Then in my application_layout I added the following code

```
<%= navigation([:games, :new, :previous, :settings]).html_safe %>
```

From what I know of Rails the html_safe should force HTML to be rendered properly, but instead what I get is this:

```
<ul class="navigation">[&quot;&lt;li class=\&quot;current\&quot;&gt;&lt;a href=\&quot;/games\&quot;&gt;Games&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&quot;, &quot;&lt;li class=\&quot;\&quot;&gt;&lt;a href=\&quot;/new\&quot;&gt;New&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&quot;, &quot;&lt;li class=\&quot;\&quot;&gt;&lt;a href=\&quot;/previous\&quot;&gt;Previous&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&quot;, &quot;&lt;li class=\&quot;\&quot;&gt;&lt;a href=\&quot;/settings\&quot;&gt;Settings&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&quot;]</ul>
```

So am I doing something wrong or is the plugin doing something wrong?  I know that the plugin was written back in 2.x days which from what I know handled HTML a bit differently, but I just don't know enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/priceflex/navigation_helper/commit/ad7bf45db1845e9299e9da39cf214866b608dd47 try to use this fork wich fix issues for rails3

Answer (score 0):

You can use raw() method to avoid escaping:

```
<%= raw(navigation([:games, :new, :previous, :settings])) %>
```

Comment: Using raw I get the same output.  What is the difference between raw and html_safe?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251284/raw-vs-html-safe-vs-h-to-unescape-html

Comment: Thanks. I think I understand now.  Raw seems better for method calls if you don't use parentheses (ex. `raw navigation [:games, :new, :previous, :settings`) whereas html_safe seems better on strings.

Comment: Still getting the same output though no matter which method I use.  Always the escaped string