# Rails/Devise how to put flash message on two lines?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'd like to use a long message on the flash notice of success when user confirms. So i'd like to display it on 2 lines using a `<br/>` on devise.en.yml

How/Where can I raw or use another method to do it ?

Here is my yml

```
en:
  devise:
    confirmations:
      confirmed: "Just confirmed loremp ipsum !!!!! !<br/> To start you up, you get full access to the website for 3 days lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum"
```

I tried to use raw here on my flash message

```
<!-- Flash messages to display alerts and notices (including success messages) -->

<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
  <% if msg.is_a?(String) %>
    <div class="alert alert-<%= name == :notice ? "success" : "error" %>">
      <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&#215;</a>
      <%=raw content_tag :div, msg, id:"flash_#{name}" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But the flash message does not understand/interpret my `<br/>` and just writes on the page `<br/>`

Comment: Isn't there a String attribute in Rails, that makes it decide whether a String object is safe or not? If so, have you tried marking the caption as safe?

Comment: i'm a newbie so i don't really understand what you say. I usually use <%=raw t("   ") %> when i want ton include html format markups such as < b/ > or < br/ > inside my yml files and it usually works. But here it's a specific problem: on devise flash message, my markup is not interpreted.

Comment: @Denis how do you mark a caption as safe ?

Comment: it looks like it's `html_safe`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300901/marking-a-string-as-html-safe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name the key `confirmed_html` or use the `.html_safe` method.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely `content_tag` is sanitizing html tags. Try:

```
<div id="flash_#{name}">
  <%= raw msg %>
</div>
```

Comment: It does work interpreting the < br/> 
But the problem is i remove 'msg' from <%=raw content_tag :div, msg, id:"flash_#{name}" %> and put it after like: 
<%= content_tag :div, id:"flash_#{name}" %><%= raw msg %>, 
then I end up with this flash message: 
“{:id=>"flash_notice"}Just confirmed loremp ipsum !!!!! ! To start you up, you get full access to the website for 3 days lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum”
I don”t want to see {:id=>"flash_notice"}:(

Comment: Note that in my example I'm not using `content_tag`.