# Rails 3 HTML Injection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-injections

Currently following the Learning Rails Screencasts at http://www.buildingwebapps.com/learningrails, making any necessary changes to work in Rails 3. However, in the tenth episode, I'm having a problem when rendering html code out of the database. The Page model in the tutorial has a body field, where the html of each page is put. The viewer controller's 'show' method grabs a Page from the database, and yields the contents of @page.body into the view. However, instead of rendering tags such as h1 properly, when I view the html source in the browser my tags are being rendered as <h1;@gt. Is there any way I can fix this?

Just for reference, my 'show' view is as follows:

```
<%= @page.body %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= raw(@page.body) %>
```

Raw method prevents escaping HTML characters.

Comment: Or `<%= @page.body.html_safe %>`. Although in this case `raw` seems to be better. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251284/raw-vs-html-safe-vs-h-to-unescape-html)