# Characters between angle brackets (<>) stripped out in database?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, html-entities

I want to store mysql regular epxression to mysql database field. Specifically I want to store word boundaries expression into the database. For example:

```
[[:<:]]my expression here[[:>:]]
```

If I put this value directly into the database (for example using Sequel Pro) the value is stored correctly.

Problem occur when I want to store this value through Ruby on Rails:

```
my_instance.sql_expression = "[[:<:]]my expression here[[:>:]]"
my_instance.save 
=> true
```

But value that is actually stored to database looks like this:

```
my_instance.sql_expression
=> "[[::]]"
```

It seems that in string Rails ignore everything what is between "<" and ">" including signs itselfs.

The project is in Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 2.3.5.

Comment: Are you certain that what is saved is mangled? I'd guess that what is mangled is the _output_. For more detailed information, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251284/raw-vs-html-safe-vs-h-to-unescape-html and see if that looks like what is going on here.

Comment: Are those examples being run from the REPL and pasted directly? (The 2nd has a typo?)

Comment: What do you get when you store `<u>Lorem Ipsum`?

Comment: I am sure that what is mangled is the value that is going from rails to database. I checked the log in terminal and of course value in database. When I store `<u>Lorem Ipsum` after a save method is called in the attribute is only `Lorem Ipsum`. I don't know how to tell that the string in the attribute is html_safe???

Comment: I just tested with 1.9.2 and rails 2.3.5. I saved values to DB string and text fields. Both values were saved correctly. Can you please go to console and save an record, reload it and see if data is OK?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you're using something like [xss_terminate](http://code.google.com/p/xssterminate/) to filter your models before saving them.  I'd look in your model definition for something which has a `before_save` or other hook that might be intrusively doing this.

This is not standard Rails behavior.