# Using helpers in a view escapes the html?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, view, helper

In my ruby on rails app I have to use recursion to render nested comments.

Because of this I decided to offload the rendering into a function in a helper.

The basic structure of the function is like this:

```
def display_comments(tree)
    to_render = ""
    to_render << render({:partial => 'comment', :locals => {:body => tree[:body]}})
    tree[:children].each do |child|
        to_render << display_comment(child)
    end
    return to_render
end
```

and in the view I call it like this:

```
<% if comment_forest.length > 0 %>
    <% comment_forest.each do |tree| %>
        <%= display_comments(tree)
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

However, on the webpage, rails escapes all the html and it ends up looking like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to call `html_safe` before you return. The sanitization behavior changed a bit in Rails 3 (XSS protection was enabled by default), so you may also want to check out [this SO discussion of `raw`, `h`, and `html_safe`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251284/raw-vs-html-safe-vs-h-to-unescape-html), which links to Yehuda Katz's [explanation of SafeBuffers in Rails 3](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/02/01/safebuffers-and-rails-3-0/).

Comment: Cool, that worked! Surprisingly, rails still escaped the html from user inputted information. What is this magic? :O

Comment: Actually in retrospect, the user inputted data is probably being escaped when it is saved not when it is displayed. Correct?

Comment: According to Katz, if you concatenate a safe string with an unsafe one, the unsafe string is first escaped, which is probably what's happening here.