# special character getting replaced

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

this is a way that i am passing subject line to a methods

```
@subject_text = html_subject(@customer_alert.alert.name)
@subject_text = html_sub(@customer_alert.alert.name)
```

and this are the two methods where i wanna replace all special character

```
def html_subject(s)
  s = s.to_s
  if s.html_safe?
    s
  else

    s.gsub(/[&amp;&gt;&lt;&quot;]/) { |special| CustomerAlert::SUBJECT_LINE[special] }
  end
 end
def html_sub(s)
  s = s.to_s
  if s.html_safe?
    s
  else

   if s.gsub(/&amp;/,'&')
   end
   #{ |special| CustomerAlert::SUBJECT_LINE[special] }

   if s.gsub(/&gt;/,'>')
   end

   if  s.gsub(/&lt;/,'<')
   end

   if s.gsub(/&quot;/,'"')

end
 s
   end
  end
```

and constant defined in model is

```
 SUBJECT_LINE = { '&amp;' => '&',  '&gt;' => '>',   '&lt;' => '<', '&quot;' => '"' }
```

but first methods call all special character is replaced by null 
and second method call not returning any value

Comment: if my case & replaced my &amd; '"' rrplaced by &quot; i wanna replace it with orignal sign

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this , you can use sanitize helper to remove special character.

Check the link :
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html

Comment: if my case & replaced my &amd; '"' rrplaced by &quot; i wanna replace it with orignal sign

Comment: where you want to display such output , I think you don't need to convert specific characters. Rails view helper will automatically convert into the desired output . use 'h', 'raw', 'html_safe' helper . For more info take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251284/raw-vs-html-safe-vs-h-to-unescape-html

Comment: i used all this thing but its not working why i am not able to identify

Comment: Try this : CGI::unescapeHTML(str)