# TinyMCE problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am using ruby on rails 3.2.1. For my post formatting I want to use TinyMCE, but I have problem with it.

1. I have installed tinymce gem and restarted server.
2. Downloaded tinymce and putted it in \myapp name\app\assets
3. My application head:

   ```
   <head>
   <title>Līvu pamatskola</title>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
   <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'style' %>
   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
   <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="D:/Projects/Myapp name/app/assets/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js" ></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" >
   tinyMCE.init({
   mode : "textareas",
   theme : "simple"   });
   </script>
   </head>
   ```
4. Made /MyApp name/config/tinymce.yml file with:

   ```
   theme_advanced_toolbar_location: top
   theme_advanced_toolbar_align: left
   theme_advanced_statusbar_location: bottom
   theme_advanced_buttons3_add:
    - tablecontrols
    - fullscreen
   plugins:
    - table
    - fullscreen
   ```
5. In /MyApp name/app/assets/javascripts/application.js

> //= require tinymce-jquery

In result I have nice formatting panel @post content field, but after saving post I can see text with html tags, not formated text. I think there is problems with installation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds as though your view is automatically escaping the html parts of your @post content field.

In your view you can do `<%= raw @post.content %>` or `<%=  @post.content.html_safe %>`

You can read this rails guide about outputting html safely http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#output-safety and this stackoverflow post about the differences between raw and html_safe [raw vs. html_safe vs. h to unescape html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251284/raw-vs-html-safe-vs-h-to-unescape-html)