# How to output html_safe within <%=%> block while concatenating strings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Consider this:

```
<%
str = "http://domain.com/?foo=1&bar=2"
%>
```

Now these cases:

```
<%=str%>
# output:http://domain.com/?foo=1&amp;bar=2

<%=str.html_safe%>
# output:http://domain.com/?foo=1&bar=2

<%="#{str.html_safe}"%>
# output:http://domain.com/?foo=1&amp;bar=2

<%=""+str.html_safe%>
# output:http://domain.com/?foo=1&amp;bar=2
```

I need to output the URL with other strings. How can I guarantee that the ampersand will be unescaped? For reasons beyond my control I can't send `&amp;`.

Please help! Pulling my hair here :\

**EDIT:** To clarify, I actually have an array like so:

```
@images = [{:id=>"fooid",:url=>"http://domain.com/?foo=1&bar=2"},...]
```

I am creating a JS array (the `image_array` var) to use in my app this way:

```
image_array.push(<%=@images.map{|x|"{id:'#{x[:id]}',url:'#{x[:url].html_safe}'}"}.join(",")%>);
```

This generates:

```
image_array.push({id:'fooid',url:'http://domain.com/?foo=1&amp;bar=2'},...);
```

Which does not work in my specific case. I need the `url` without the `amp;` part.

Comment: that's where the "reasons beyond my control" part comes to play... I didn't do the receiver and have no control on that... and it is an image `src`... no that it makes any difference

Comment: FWIW try this: http://images.nypl.org/index.php?id=g92f032_015zf&t=r vs http://images.nypl.org/index.php?id=g92f032_015zf&amp;t=r

Comment: @phrogz added a clarification which might help... thanks

Comment: I've deleted all my noise. Note that you still need to encode the ampersand if you are inside a `<script>` block [in XHTML](http://phrogz.net/tmp/ampersand_in_xhtml.xhtml) (but not if you are [in HTML](http://phrogz.net/tmp/ampersand_in_html.html)).

Comment: got it. I rephrased the question so it is more clear what I'm trying to solve. I don't really want to know the difference btw `<%=` and `<%=#{` but how to output an html_safe within a group of concatenated strings... as you can see from case 4 up there: `<%=""+str.html_safe` doesn't work either

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you write:

```
"#{foo.bar}"
```

this is ~equivalent to writing

```
foo.bar.to_s
```

So what you are actually doing is:

```
<%=str.html_safe.to_s%>
```

…which Rails no longer sees as being safe, and so it hits your resulting string with a round of HTML escaping.

*I don't know the internals of Rails, but I assume that the `html_safe` method extends the string object with an instance variable flagging it as OK, but when you wrap that in another string via interpolation you are getting a new string without that flag.*

**Edit**: To answer your needs, use `raw` or call `html_safe` on your final string:

```
<%=raw "foo#{str}"%>
<%="foo#{str}".html_safe%>
```

or in your case:

```
image_array.push(<%=raw @images.map{…}.join(',')%>);
image_array.push(<%=@images.map{…}.join(',').html_safe%>);
```

*See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251284/raw-vs-html-safe-vs-h-to-unescape-html).*

Comment: but how do you output an `html_safe` string within a concatenation?

Comment: BTW, why are you manually generating JSON instead of using standard JSON generation?

Comment: Always nice to see a bit of explanation so people know what's going on.

Comment: to be fair rails does this because concatenating a safe string and an unsafe string does result in an unsafe string, so as always **be careful with your raw/html_safe**

Answer (score 2):

Use  this

```
    <%=str.html_safe.to_s%>
```

or

```
   <%=raw(str)%>
```

give you better results

Comment: how can I concatenate that to another string within the same `<%` block?

Answer (score 0):

```
image_array.push(<%= @images.map{|x| "{id:'#{x[:id]}',url:'#{x[:url]}'}".html_safe }.join(",") %>);
```

Comment: No, once you call `join` not the array you will create a new string that is no longer flagged as being safe.

Comment: I would agree, if I hadn't tested it myself on RoR 3.2. Printed result to the log and it worked. Although I'd question if it's the desired result, the & is correctly unescaped.

Answer (score 0):

what you would do to be safe is:

```
image_array.push(<%= @images.map { |image| image.as_json(only: [:id, :url]) }.to_json } %>)
```

this will escape the `<`, `>`, etc. properly like this:

```
[{"name":"\u003ch1\u003eAAAA\u003c/h1\u003e"}]
```

and for people coming here like me who want to concatenate strings, it's just not safe to do it, the best way is to concatenate tags, e.g.

```rb
    content_tag(:p) do
      content_tag(:span, "<script>alert(1)</script>") +
        link_to("show", user)
    end
```

will work fine and properly escape the first string