# Block with link_to on one line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

How do I do the following in one line?

```
<% song.albums.each do |album| %>
  <%= link_to album.title, album %><br />
<% end %>
```

I've tried two approaches that haven't worked.

This gives me the entire array:

```
<%= song.albums.each {|album| link_to album.title, album } %>
```

And this output is blank:

```
<% song.albums.each {|album| link_to album.title, album } %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= song.albums.map{ |a| link_to(a.title,a) }.join("<br/>").html_safe %>
```

If you really need/want the extra `<br/>` after the last item, then either put it after this block, or use:

```
<%= song.albums.map{ |a| "#{link_to(a.title,a)}<br/>" }.join.html_safe %>
```

*Note that using an explicit `<br/>` in your HTML is usually "code smell"; you should probably be using CSS `display:block` on the anchor or on a wrapping element like `<li>` instead.*

Comment: I had to wrap this in raw() to get the html output. But it works great. Thanks so much.

Comment: @Brett See my edit; you can also [use `html_safe`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251284/raw-vs-html-safe-vs-h-to-unescape-html) to achieve your needs. I prefer this over `raw` as the intent is more obvious.

Comment: Very good. As for the <br/>, I'm saving all the CSS formatting for the end of the project. I agree that it's tacky for now. Thanks again.