# list the items of a join method in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, methods

I have a method that joins the items within my array and when they are called to the view they are presented as a sentence would, all on one line.

```
def ingredient_names(ingredients)
if ingredients
  ingredient_array = ingredients.map {|ing| ing.ingredient_name}
  ingredient_array.join("\n")
end
end
```

how would i go about getting each item in the array to appear as a list? so for example

```
flour
eggs
water
```

is there a method for this or would i change the

```
("\n)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
def ingredient_names(ingredients)
  return ''  if !ingredients

  ingredients.map(&:ingredient_name)*'<br/>'
end
```

in the view call it like

```
<%= raw(ingredient_names(ingredients)) %>
```

Comment: however, this works raw(ingredient_names(@recipe.ingredients))  thanks for your help

Comment: can i ask why this works, what is going on, raw outputs html?

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251284/raw-vs-html-safe-vs-h-to-unescape-html)