# html from flash helper is showing in my Rails 3 displayed page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a helper in application_helper to show my flash messages.  The code is based on code I found on Stack Overflow, with my modifications:

```
   def show_flash
     flash_names = [:notice, :warning, :message, :error]
     flash_html = ''
     for name in flash_names
       if flash[name]
         flash_html = flash_html + "<div class=\"#{name}\">#{flash[name]}</div>"
       end
       flash[name] = nil;
     end
     flash_html
   end
```

When I run this, instead of getting the flash message on my page, I get the actual html that my show_flash helper generated, including all the markup:

```
      <div class="notice">Item was successfully updated.</div>
```

My application.html.erb file looks like this:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
   <title>My Application</title>
   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
 </head>
 <body>
<h1 align="center">Welcome to XYZ Application</c></h1>
<%= show_flash %>

 <%= yield %>

 </body>
 </html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: return flash_html.html_safe instead of flash_html

Answer (score 1):

You need to make add `.html_safe` to make it treat as an HTML element

```
def show_flash
   flash_names = [:notice, :warning, :message, :error]
   flash_html = ''
   for name in flash_names
     if flash[name]
       flash_html = flash_html + "<div class=\"#{name}\">#{flash[name]}</div>"
     end
     flash[name] = nil;
   end
   flash_html.html_safe # added this to make it appear as an HTML element instead of as real string
 end
```

You can see the different options in this question, [raw vs. html_safe vs. h to unescape html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251284/raw-vs-html-safe-vs-h-to-unescape-html). The code, you referred to might have been written in Rails 2. In Rails 3, any string that is outputted in the html page is HTML escaped by default. In Rails 2, we needed to use `h` helper for escaping HTML, but in Rails 3, it is escaped by default. So, if you really need to show unescaped HTML, you need to make use of either `raw` or `.html_safe`. `raw` can be called only from the views and controllers, so in the helpers, you might use `html_safe`.

Comment: Perfect, that fixed it!  Thank you for your help, and for such a quick response

Comment: @user1904869..you can accept the answer by clicking on the tick mark on the left side of my answer ([image](http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-accept-answer.png))