# Returning HTML from a Ruby Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm trying to create a Ruby gem that returns html mark up like so:

```
class Hola
    def self.hi(name = "world")
        "hello #{name}"
    end

    def self.hi_with_markup(name = "world")
        "<strong>hello #{name}</strong>"
    end
end
```

However, whenever I try to use it in a test.html.erb file like so:

```
<%= Hola.hi_with_markup(", please work!") %>
```

It returns the string with the  tags printed instead of actually rendering the html.  How can I fix this from the gem side?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In Rails 3 the default changed from "not" escaping HTML to escaping HTML (i.e. converting things like '>' to &gt;) for any String deemed to be unsafe; which is generally any string that has the potential to have user characters, including the output of your gem.  There are two ways around this `raw()` and `.html_safe`.

Here's a comprehensive answer: [raw vs. html_safe vs. h to unescape html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251284/raw-vs-html-safe-vs-h-to-unescape-html)

The short answer is to do this:

```
<%= Hola.hi_with_markup(", please work!").html_safe %>
```

or

```
<%= raw(Hola.hi_with_markup(", please work!")) %>
```

Comment: i see, if that's the case then there doesn't seem to be any way around it.  do you know if there's a way to return output from an html file instead of hardcoding the html markup in rb file.

Comment: Actually, there may be one way around it: You'd have to work with the ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer directly. According to this article, http://yehudakatz.com/2010/02/01/safebuffers-and-rails-3-0/ that is the actual object that you're working with in a ERB template. So you could have your gem work with SafeBuffers instead of Strings and then ensure that the "safe" flag was set before returning.

Comment: As far as working with files, do you want your gem to return the contents of a file? Or do you want to load and display a file in Rails? Or am I missing the use case entirely?

Comment: so ideally i'd like to have a partial inside the gem that can be customized based on what parameters are passed to it from a rails project.  so like in the question above, the "<strong>hello #{name}</strong>" would be in a _partial.html and a call to Hola.hi_with_markup("bob") would return the contents of the partial with "bob".  Make sense?  Not sure if this is possible with a gem or if I should be using a plugin.

Comment: It makes sense. I often call my partials from a helper simply because I find that it looks cleaner, IMHO. So it sounds like you're trying to do the same thing except in a way that is share-able. Is it definitely something you need to share across multiple Rails projects? If so, I'd try experimenting with the ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer directly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class Hola
    def self.hi(name = "world")
        "hello #{name}"
    end

    def self.hi_with_markup(name = "world")
        "<strong>hello #{name}</strong>".to_html
    end
end
```

Comment: undefined method `to_html' for "<strong>hello , please work!</strong>":String

Comment: Ah, that method may be a Rails method and not a Ruby method. I couldn't remember off hand if it was or not.