# How to convert an array into content_tags in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to write a helper function in Rails that converts an array of values into an array of `radio_buttons`. In my form I have this:

```
<%= radio_tags_for_select(f.object.invoice_types) %>
```

This is my helper function:

```
def radio_tags_for_select(array)
  options = []
  array.each do |value|
    options << content_tag(:span, value, :class => 'radio_option')
  end
  options
end
```

Unfortunately, the function spits out only raw HTML which I can't really use. Is there a more elegant solution to this, maybe even using a `radio_tag` helper?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you using RoR 3, 3.1, or 3.2?  Please limit your tags accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in a single line of code:

```
f.object.invoice_types.collect {|e| radio_button_tag("my_radio_button_name", e) }
```

Now, is that what you want? An array of radio buttons?

Comment: OK, thanks, but this generates some raw HTML. I am still new to Rails, so how can I escape it?

Comment: you can use the helper h to escape it:

<%= h f.object.invoice_types.collect {|e| radio_button_tag("my_radio_button_name", e) } %>

Comment: Now, if the problem is that helper is already escaping the html, and you want to get the html not to be escaped, you can do:

(f.object.invoice_types.collect {|e| radio_button_tag("my_radio_button_name", e) }).html_safe

to tell rails that is ok to render that string as html, although radio_button_tag already mark the string as html safe

Comment: Unfortunately, none of this is working here. The HTML comes out unescaped, no matter what I do.

Comment: so when you say its unescaped, on the screen, instead of seeing the radio buttons, you see the html code, right? if that's the case, then its escaped, you escape the code to avoid xss attacks.
You can do: raw <%= f.object.invoice_types.collect {|e| radio_button_tag("my_radio_button_name", e) } %>
Please check this question that it explains the differences on escaping and not escaping code in rail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251284/raw-vs-html-safe-vs-h-to-unescape-html