# Rails 4 raw html_safe not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, html-safe

I am not able to escape raw html tags in the view

```
<% array =  @article.tags.collect { |p| (link_to p.name, '#') } %>
<%= array.join(' , ') %>
```

Raw and html_safe

```
<% array =  @article.tags.collect { |p| raw (link_to p.name, '#') } %>
<% array =  @article.tags.collect { |p| (link_to p.name, '#').html_safe } %>
```

Giving me this output, without escaping the html tags

```
<a href="#">tag1</a> , <a href="#">tag2</a> , <a href="#">tag4</a>
```

Comment: also explained at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251284/raw-vs-html-safe-vs-h-to-unescape-html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This solved my problem

```
<%= raw (@article.tags.map { |p| (link_to p.name, '#') }.join(' , ')) %>
```