# Rendering model errors like JSON in js template

Tags: ajax, json, ruby-on-rails-3, model, error-handling

I am submitting form with *data-remote=true* attribute. The *create* action in the controller looks like:

```
format.js { @user }
```

and it is handled by the following template:

```
create.js.erb
```

Is there an easy way to render the @user.errors messages like JSON in order to used the following JSON in the current template and handle the errors then?

I know that I can render the errors using *format.json* directive but I want to make and other JavaScript manipulation, not only render the errors and because of this I am using the *format.js* tehnique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This easily can be solved by using [to_json](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json) method. In order to render the passed model object I only should do:

```
var current_errors = <%=  @security_user.errors.to_json %>;
```

Anyway, this was still not rendering a proper JSON because the quotes were being automatically encoded by rails (to prevent XSS), so you should use one of the following methods:

1. [html_safe](http://apidock.com/rails/String/html_safe)
2. [raw](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/RawOutputHelper/raw)
3. h

More information about them can be found here - [raw vs. html_safe vs. h to unescape html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251284/raw-vs-html-safe-vs-h-to-unescape-html)

And the final solution that works for me is:

```
var current_errors = <%=  raw @security_user.errors.to_json %>;
```