# how to get hanzq/youtube_addy gem working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I have a rails app that allows users to submit youtube links and rank the songs/links using the thumbs up gem.

However, users must physically copy and paste the link into the browser to listen to the song after the link is uploaded. For a better UX I'm going to use [this gem](https://github.com/hanzq/youtube_addy) to dynamically embed the YouTube video into my app once the users upload the link.

However, I'm not quite sure how this can be done?

I was thinkin' of doing something like this in the index:

```
 <%= YouTubeAddy.extract_video_id('song.url)' %> <%= YouTubeAddy.youtube_embed_url('song.url') %> ?
```

or would it have to be in the controller? and if so how?

**song#new.html.erb:**

```
<%= form_for @song, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
<% if @song.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@song.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this song from being saved:</h2>

     <ul>
      <% @song.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-6 columns">
    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label 'website url' %>
    <%= f.text_area :url %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :tag_list, "Genres (separated by commas)" %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :tag_list %>
    </div>
    <p>
    <%= f.file_field :track%>
    </p>

    <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit value: "Upload" %>
    </div>

    <% end %>
        </div>
```

**song_controller.rb**

```
class SongsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:create ,:edit, :update, :destroy, :vote_for_song]
  before_action :set_song, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :vote_for_song]

  def vote_for
      @song = Song.find(params[:id])
      current_user.vote_for(@song)
      @song.plusminus = @song.votes_for
      @song.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js { render 'update_votes' }
      end
  end

  def vote_against
    @song = Song.find(params[:id])
    current_user.vote_against(@song)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render 'update_votes' }
    end
  end

  def new_songs
    @songs = Song.order "id DESC"
  end


  # GET /Songs
  # GET /Songs.json
  def index
    if params[:genre]
      @songs = Song.tagged_with(params[:genre]).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15)
    else
      @songs = Song.order('plusminus').paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15)
    end
  end

  # GET /Songs/1
  # GET /Songs/1.json
  def show
   @comment = Comment.new(song: @song) 
  end

  # GET /Songs/new
  def new
    @song = Song.new
  end

  # GET /Songs/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /Songs
  # POST /Songs.json
  def create
    @song = Song.new(song_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @song.save
        format.html { redirect_to @song, notice: 'Song was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @song }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @song.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /Songs/1
  # PATCH/PUT /Songs/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @song.update(song_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @song, notice: 'Song was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @song.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # Song /Songs/1
  # Song /Songs/1.json
  def destroy
    @song.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to songs_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private

    def set_song
       @song = Song.find(params[:id])
     end

     def song_params
       params.require(:song).permit(:title, :artist, :url, :track, :user_id, :tag_list)
     end
  end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<h6>Top ranked songs</h6>
<hr>
<ol><% @songs.each do |song| %>
<span class="title">
<li><%=link_to image_tag('thumbs.png', size: '16x50'), vote_for_song_path(song), :remote => true, :method => :put %> <%= link_to song.title, song %><span class="subtext"> (<%= song.url %>)<br></li></span>


 <%#=link_to '&#9660'.html_safe, vote_against_song_path(song), :remote => true, :method => :put %> 

<span class="subtext"><span class="votes_<%= song.id %>"><%= pluralize(song.votes.count, 'like') %>,</span>

    posted <%= time_ago_in_words(song.created_at) + " ago" %>
    <small><span class="comments"></small> | <%= pluralize(song.comments.size, 'comment') %></span></small><br /></span>


<%#= link_to 'Show', song, class: "button small secondary" %>
<%= link_to('Edit', edit_song_path(song), class: "button small secondary") if can? :update, song %>
<%= link_to('Destroy', song, method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'}, class: "button small secondary") if can? :destroy, song %>

<% end %>

</ol>
<div class="pagination-centered">
  <ul class="pagination">
<%#= will_paginate @songs %>
<!-- or custom pagination -->
<% if @songs.previous_page %>
  <%= link_to "Back", params.merge(page: @songs.previous_page) %>
<% end %>
<% if @songs.next_page %>
  <%= link_to "More", params.merge(page: @songs.next_page) %>
<% end %>
</ul></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`YouTubeAddy.youtube_embed_url('song.url')` generates a string of iframe tag, so it should be used in your view exactly where you want an embedded video to be placed. But note that you should return an html safe string. So in your view you have:

```
<%=raw YouTubeAddy.youtube_embed_url('song.url') %>
```

More about [unescaping html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251284/raw-vs-html-safe-vs-h-to-unescape-html).