# Title tag is escaped twice in Rails/HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, escaping, haml, title

I have a Rails 3.2.13 app in which I have titles that contain the site name and a page specific text. The common part is defined in the layout and the page specific part in each HAML view.

First I used `provide` like this:

```
# layout.html.haml
%title= (content_for?(:title) ? "#{yield(:title)} | " : "") + "Chunky-B"

# show.html.haml
- provide(:title, @listing.name)
```

My problem is that when the page specific content is pulled from a model it gets **escaped twice**. If `@listing.name` contains an (unescaped) ampersand I get the output

```
<title>Bacon &amp;amp; Eggs | Chunky-B</title>
```

I recently switched to using [the `meta-tags` gem](https://github.com/kpumuk/meta-tags) for my titles and meta descriptions, but the same issue persists.

I understand that I need some combination of `h`, `html_safe` or maybe even `raw`. With the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4251284/454094) and some trial and error I would probably get there, but I haven't had to bypass built-in escaping before and don't feel like second-guessing myself at the risk of opening vulnerabilities. I got a hunch of how it should be done while writing this question, but I'm betting eager SO answerers will beat me to it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual, I was looking at the answer all along.

I get the result that I wanted by using `(h @listing.name).html_safe` as per [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4251284/454094#comment8008498_4252113), and if I am to believe the commenter it is "common and accepted use".

If I understand it correctly, I force the name to be escaped with `h` to protect me from all kinds of evil, and then mark it as not needing any additional escaping with the `.html_safe` call.

Everything looks fine, the output is escaped once and renders correctly in my browser title bar. I could use some reassurance that this is safe and sound, though. And if someone could give a quality answer as to *why* I don't get the same result out of the box, I would be ready to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced this issue, and it appears to only happen when the title is passed as a simple content:

```
content_for :title, 'Wow & Fail'
#=> Wow &amp;amp; Fail
```

But when it's passed as a block it renders correctly:

```
content_for :title do
  'Wow & Fail'
#=> Wow & Fail
```

As you can see here https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/76c385709c873a7105e3a267d84c4e70417a15e2/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb#L153

The capture method is being used only if you pass a block, which utilizes active_support's output_safety https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/76c385709c873a7105e3a267d84c4e70417a15e2/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb#L41

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same thing and discovered a safer solution than using `html_safe`.

First, the updated code:

```
# layout.html.haml
%title = full_title("Chunky-B")
```

where "safe_title" is:

```
def full_title(page_title)
  base_title = "".html_safe
  if content_for?(:title)
    base_title << yield(:title)
    base_title << " | "
  end
  base_title << page_title
  base_title
end
```

This escapes `:title` content if it is unsafe, but leaves it unescaped if it is safe. (Granted, you'll likely want to method-ize this, since I've turned your one-liner into a six-liner.)

This allows a title of `"Bacon & Eggs"` to display properly, but also escapes `"<script>alert('foo')</script>"` -- for instance, if some malicious user manages to enter custom text into a field that is displayed in a title tag, or if you ever accidentally use risky text yourself.

The explanation boils down to this -- `'foo'.html_safe` returns an ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer which acts like a String in every way except one: When you append a String to a SafeBuffer (by calling + or <<), that other String is HTML-escaped before it is appended to the SafeBuffer. When you append another SafeBuffer to a SafeBuffer, no escaping will occur. Rails is rendering all of your views under the hood using SafeBuffers, so the updated method above ends up providing Rails with a SafeBuffer that we've controlled to perform escaping on the `:title` "as-needed" rather than "always".

Now, the credit for this answer goes entirely to Henning Koch, and is explained in far more detail at [Everything you know about html_safe is wrong](http://makandracards.com/makandra/2579-everything-you-know-about-html_safe-is-wrong) -- my recap above attempts only to provide the essence of the explanation in the event that this link ever dies.

Comment: Does your code snipped really do what you want? I'm not sure about `%haml_tag <<` - I don't think it appends something to a HAML tag!

Comment: Thanks -- fixed answer. I had attempted to tweak the lesson to fit the OP, and didn't realize I couldn't `%haml_tag <<`. (In my own projects I've methodized this anyway.) The bulk of the answer logic remains applicable -- the alternate answer (using `.html_safe` only) *is* common, but leaves you open to script injection.