# How to quote html markup for Javascript in rails, if your response content type is "text/html"?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, content-type, quotes, html-escape-characters

I'm building a site with lots of file uploads, I use BlueImp's jQuery fileupload [plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)

It goes smooth until IE: Firstly, IE9 tries to download the .js file and complains about "dangerous content". I fixed it by setting the content_type to text/plain as it said in the plugin's [documentation](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Setup#content-type-negotiation).

In IE8, even if "text/plain" is set, IE tries to download the .js file again so I tried to "**text/html**" and it worked... with simple scripts responses.

However, functions inserting HTML with `after()` or `html()` fail.

Some code in rails:

```
$(this).html("<%=j image_tag(@ph.image.url(:thumb)) %>");
```

In IE's connection debugger (F12) the response text looks like:

```
$(this).html("<img alt=\"2\" src=\"/system/phs/images/000/000/601/thumb/2.jpg?1378955682\" />");
```

but at the same time my development log tells me that there was a bad uri request:

```
[2013-09-12 12:14:44] ERROR bad URI `/%22/system/placeholders/images/000/000/601/thumb/2.jpg?1378955682\\"'.
```

So I supose it is a problem with some text transformation which happens when IE receive my js script and in its header content type is text/html. Please, help me with that, may be I miss some quotation rules?

Comment: It looks like the escaped quotes are getting turned into HTML escape character %22, see this question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251284/raw-vs-html-safe-vs-h-to-unescape-html