# How to add HTML instead of just text as the page title in Refinery CMS?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, refinerycms

Currently to enter the title of a page, all you have to do is enter the text in the WYSIWYG editor.

[image: enter wysiwyg]

But if you enter HTML like `example title about stuff&trade; by company&copy;` or in my case

[image: what i entered]

then you get a result with no html, like

[image: result of html]

So my question is how to make changes in Refinery so that the title can accept HTML?

I looked the the [documentation about page titles](http://refinerycms.com/guides/page-titles-and-urls) but that topic was not addressed.

Comment: I don't know about Refinery but what you need is `.html_safe` method, to "translate" html tags of a string into actual html tags.

Comment: Thank you @MrYoshiji, that got me looking at [this post about .html_safe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251284/raw-vs-html-safe-vs-h-to-unescape-html). So it looks like I just have to locate the controller for that view now.

Comment: Page titles are not handled by a controller, but by the ContentPagePresenter. Here's the code for version 2.1: https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms/blob/2-1-stable/pages/app/presenters/refinery/pages/content_page_presenter.rb