# What is the opposite of html_escape in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

What is the opposite of `html_escape` function? Why isn't there an html_unescape?

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ERB/Util.html#method-c-html_escape

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251284/raw-vs-html-safe-vs-h-to-unescape-html

Comment: Thanks, I already have an escaped string. I really, really, really want to unescape it.

Comment: Is the `h` function what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe [this](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html#method-c-unescape) class method from CGI class in ruby?

Comment: Thanks! I found it too and was just about to post the answer! Actually, you linked to URI unescape, for `%20` characters, and I needed #unescapeHTML for `&#39;` characters, but it's close enough! [CGI::unescapeHTML](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI/Util.html#method-i-unescapeHTML)

Answer (score 0):

`raw` might be what you are looking for.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper.html#method-i-raw