# displaying html content from database

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

i have this in my database :

```
<p><u>kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk &nbsp;&nbsp;</u><strong>kknk&nbsp;</strong></p>
```

When i want to display my database content, this code isn't interpreted as html.
It is just displayed as text. i would like this content to be interpreted. (so  will give a bold text,  an underlined word etc..).

Comment: You probably have code somewhere that is escaping the HTML.

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to display the content? It's at *that* point that you would render the content as HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just put:

```
<%=content.html_safe%>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are a bit more ways:

```
<%= raw content %>
<%= h content %>
<%= content.html_safe %>
```

and a comparison:

[raw vs. html_safe vs. h to unescape html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251284/raw-vs-html-safe-vs-h-to-unescape-html)