# How to render HTML tag, rather than printing it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, font-awesome

I am using a decorator for an object called `@menu` to render a link in my view. I am also using Draper gem for my decorators.

In my decorator, I have something in the lines of:

```
def link
  link_to model.name + icon("external-link"), model.url
end
```

But when I call this in my view using `@menu.link`, the html tag for `<i>` will be literally displayed on the page, instead of being processed.

By the way, I can render the same html by using a helper from the font-awesome gem: `icon("external-link")`. But it will yield the same result. Could anyone show me how to properly render the html in this case?

Comment: you should use `html_safe` on the link method. 
Something like this `<%= @menu.link.html_safe %>`

Comment: Remove quotation mark: (model.name + "<i class="<--- THIS QUOTATION MARK IS EXTRA> fa fa-external-link></i>", model.url)

Comment: @RedZagogulin Sorry, that was a typo. I edited my question.

Comment: @PamioSolanky I called `html_safe`, but I still see the raw html. I also tried to call `html_safe` within the method definition by doing `link_to (model.name + icon('external_link').html_safe, model.url)`.

Comment: NOt sure why this should happen. 
You could also use `raw` like this `= raw @menu.link` ?? Let me know

Comment: @PamioSolanky Thanks for your suggestion. But when I try '<%= raw @menu.link %>`, I still see the raw html.

Comment: @PamioSolanky I resolved it by calling `html_safe` on `(model.name + icon('external-link)` altogether. (as per @Hannes's answer)

Comment: @MikeC - perfect, more information about html_safe / raw / h methods can be find in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251284/raw-vs-html-safe-vs-h-to-unescape-html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using font-awesome-sass gem it would be smart to use the #icon helper method. In your case:

```
def link_with_icon
  link_to (model.name + icon('external-link')).html_safe, model.url
end
```