# Prevent instance variable to encode in html within js file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, renderpartial

I have an instance method in my controller, for example

```
@instance_var =  [{:id=>7142,
  :t_id=>"5888",
  :date=>Mon, 10 Mar 2014,
  :name=>"test"]
```

From my controller, I have rendered a js to call a partial file.

In this js file, my instance variable is encoded in HTML like `"` is encoded to `&quot;` and `=>`is encoded to `=&gt;`. That's why I am having problems in calling a partial file with `collection`. Partial files are not iterating to each instance_var key-value pair.

```
$('#element_id').html('<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "my_partial", :collection => @instance_var)) %>')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [raw](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/RawOutputHelper/raw) method that is available in rails.
There's also html_safe and some other options, you can read about them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251284/raw-vs-html-safe-vs-h-to-unescape-html).

Comment: I cannot use html_safe as I'm in JS file. It says undefined method `html_safe`. I actually want to change my instance variable so that I can use it in `collection` to iterate it in partial file.