# is strip_tags(unsafe_string).html_safe safe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xss, sanitization

We want to let our users use html entities in their content, but don't want to be exposed to the scripting attacks. So, we use following:

```
strip_tags(unsafe_string).html_safe
```

As far as I understand it should be safe, as long as no *valid* tag should appear in the output. On the other hand, I can image situation when browser will render an invalid tag, which won't be sanitized by the helper. Should I be concerned about that?

Thanks.

Comment: Please check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251284/raw-vs-html-safe-vs-h-to-unescape-html

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it is not supposed to escape `&` or `<`, so its `html_safe` being false is supposed to be correct. So you should not mark it as html_safe.

However, recent version of Rails starts to escape these two characters, and this is considered a bug, but was not fixed yet as of Rails 4.2.5.2 (https://github.com/rails/rails-html-sanitizer/issues/28)