# How to display in view formated from hash text with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, hash

root.rb

```
root 'builders#result'
    post 'builders/calc'
```

builders_controller.rb

```
class BuildersController < ApplicationController

    def result
    end

    def calc
      @hash = {0 => ["a", "b", "c"],1 => ["x", "y", "z"]}
      @text = @hash.values.map{ |v| v.join(',') }.join("\n")
      @result = @text
    end
end
```

result.html.erb

```
<div id="total"></div>
```

calc.js.erb
$('#total').html('<%= @result %>')

If I post @result like `@result = @hash.values`
I can see the result as `[["a", "b", "c"], ["x", "y", "z"]]` but `@result = @hash.values.map{ |v| v.join(',') }.join("\n")` not working?

Seems like problem with `.join("\n")` but I need to save option to see each formated value from new line

Any fix?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [simple_format](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/simple_format) helper:

```
<%= simple_format(@result) %>
```

There is also a [pretty neat code](https://gist.github.com/sandipransing/6914650) to do it in jQuery

Another answer that might interest you: [raw vs. html_safe vs. h to unescape html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251284/raw-vs-html-safe-vs-h-to-unescape-html)