# Is there way to use link_to tag inside controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, link-to

I want to use link_to tag inside a controller.
I added `include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper` and here is the my code.

```
def authenticate_user!
    unless user_signed_in?
        flash[:danger] ="You must sign in or sign up first!#{link_to("test", root_path) }".html_safe
        redirect_to new_session_path
    end
end
```

If I go to the browser, it shows `You must sign in or sign up first!<a href="/">test</a>`

Do you know how can I show this message correctly? (I mean without  tag)

Thank you!

Comment: Where do you render out the `flash[:danger]` message in your view or layout?

Comment: `flash` messages are stored in the session and read from it again when the user loads the next page. Therefore the `html_safe` has no effect in this case because when read from the session the string is considered unsafe again.

Comment: on the view/layout where you render the `flash`, you need to call `raw flash[:danger]`. Read more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251284/raw-vs-html-safe-vs-h-to-unescape-html

Comment: @tadman Yes, I pass this data to view and use content_tag to show this message.

Comment: @spickermann ok! But either way I have html_safe or not, I still can not show the message properly. I mean it shows with <a> tag around the message.