# Set string of html as Html just like innerHTML without JavaScript directly from .html file

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

In embedded ruby(html.erb) file,

I have a string  of html like `variable_string = "<p>Some <strong>Content</strong></p>".`

Using Javascript we can just update DOM like `Element.innerHTML = variable_string` and the string will be rendered as html.

But I can't use JavaScript and want to do something like

```
<div innerHTML="<%= variable_string %>">
```

directly sort of inline way. Is it possible?

Comment: Use `html_safe` on the `variable_string`. Refer this for more - https://stackoverflow.com/a/39706146/4758119

Answer (score 0, accepted):

string.html_safe and other approach is ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper